# Получение ширины элемента после изменения его высоты

Tags: javascript, promise

Мне необходимо сразу после того как элементу задана высота, получить его **computed** ширину.

Вариант с event transitionend. В CSS файле 'transition: height 1ms' есть. По какой-то причине getComputedStyle выдает иногда 0px

```
        const someElems = [elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4];
        let arrWidth: string[] = [];
        for (const element of someElems) {
            element.addEventListener("transitionend", () => arrWidth.push(window.getComputedStyle(element).width) );
            //после изменения высоты, обработчик события не запускается
            element.style.height = heightRow;
        }
```

Решение не найдено. Работает только с искусственно созданной задержкой. Каждый раз getComputed возвращают верные значения.

```
        const someElems = [elem1, elem2, elem3, elem4];
        const height = "350px"
        let arrWidth: string[] = [];
        for (const element of someElems) {
            element.addEventListener("transitionend", () => arrWidth.push(window.getComputedStyle(element).width) );
            setTimeout(() => {
                element.style.height = height;
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Comment: в текущем виде у тебя все синхронно выполняется.

Comment: Думаю, если цель - получить новую ширину , после изменения высоты: то надо дождаться события деформации https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event .

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр , 
Использую сейчас этот прослушиватель с transitionend. Но событие после изменения высоты не происходит

Comment: Зачем вы делаете `return new Promise` в async функции? И зачем тут вообще промисы?

Comment: @Владимир Говоров если у элемента нет свойства transition, то transitionend не будет работать

Comment: Promises на самом деле там совсем не к месту.
И у элемента есть и было свойство `transition: height 1ms'. Дело в том, что изначально элементу не была задана высота явно, вот и transition не отрабатывал.

Comment: И по какой причине понижение рейтинга - понять не могу. Я ведь задаю вопрос не просто с бухты барахты, а по причине не знания, и по причине того, что не смог найти ответ самостоятельно. 

Если ставите минус рейтингу - хотя бы объясните из-за чего, чтобы в дальнейшем такие особи как я не допускали таких ошибок.

Comment: работает только с искусственно созданной задержкой

Comment: сделай [mcve] чтобы можно было прям тут запустить и увидеть проблему: [Что такое сниппеты?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4619/186999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете следить за изменениями ваших элементов при помощи ResizeObserver
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

```js
  let div = document.querySelector('div');
  let btn = document.querySelector('button');
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => div.style.height = '120px');

  const ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
          console.log(entry.contentBoxSize);
      });
  })

  ro.observe(div);
```

```css
div {  
  height: 70px;
  aspect-ratio: 2/1;  
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  тест тест тест тест тест тест тест
</div>

<button>изменить</button>
```